# Why is this line of code leaks memory?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, memory-leaks

I have found a line of code that is leaking memory in my project. It's a DllImport method:

```
[DllImport("OpenCL")] public static extern Error clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(OpenCLCommandQueue command_queue, OpenCLKernel kernel, Int32 work_dim, [In] IntPtr[] global_work_offset, [In] IntPtr[] global_work_size, [In] IntPtr[] local_work_size, Int32 num_events_in_wait_list, [In] OpenCLEvent[] event_wait_list, out OpenCLEvent e);
```

It is called with this code:

```
OpenCLEvent e;

OpenCLDriver.clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(CommandQueue.OpenCLCommandQueue, OpenCLKernel, globalWorkSize.Length, globalWorkOffset, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, eventWaitList.Count, eventWaitList.OpenCLEventArray, out e);

return null;
```

Things such as CommandQueue.OpenCLCommandQueue and other arguments are ordinary properties or variables which can't leak memory, there are no code behind them.

I don't understand how can clEnqueueNDRangeKernel call leak memory? Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you know it is leaking memory?

Comment: I looked into taskmgr, it shows around 10 mb/sec of allocations. In five minutes program allocates around 2 gb of memory and then crashes if you comment out the "OpenCLDriver.clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" everything works fine

Comment: One important question is if it is leaking managed or unmanaged memory.

Comment: I think it can't be managed, it would then be GC'ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that there was a memory leak problem in OpenCL with `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` known since 2009, fixed 2010...

http://www.opentk.com/node/1541?page=3
http://forums.amd.com/devforum/messageview.cfm?catid=390&threadid=122161&highlight_key=y

Comment: Aren't your links about different issues? To me it sounds like the first one is about bugs in the wrapper, the second one in the amd library.

Comment: true - but both result in a memory leak... since I don't know enough about the OPs case I posted both...

Comment: Hey my problem is the same to the one that CLOO had, opencl allocates additional memory behind the OpenCLEvent which should be released THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
clFinish(CommandQueue);
```

after

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel
```